# Keyboard Issue With Framelayout

Tags: android, xml

I've an EditText on my Layout which is a Framelayout, the problem is when I finish entering some data in the EditText then I press the back button on the mobile to hide the keypad, it keeps showing a shadow of the keypad until I press any where on the activity.

HOW I CAN SOLVE THIS PROBLEM.

Here is what happen after I press the back button the hide the keypad, I have to press again on the activity to make the black shadow disappears.(Check the Black Shadow in the Bottom)

[image: Keypad Problem]

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
```

activty_main.xml

```
<com.example.layout.MainLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_content_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout></com.example.layout.MainLayout>
```

Updated:-
MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

// The MainLayout which will hold both the sliding menu and our main content
// Main content will holds our Fragment respectively
MainLayout mainLayout;

// ListView menu
private ListView lvMenu;
private String[] lvMenuItems;

// Menu button
TextView btMenu;

// Title according to fragment
TextView tvTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Inflate the mainLayout
    mainLayout = (MainLayout)this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    setContentView(mainLayout);
    lvMenuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);
    lvMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_menu_listview);
    lvMenu.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lvMenuItems));
    lvMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            onMenuItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
        }

    });

    // Get menu button
    btMenu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_content_button_menu);
    btMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Show/hide the menu
            toggleMenu(v);
        }
    });

    // Get title textview
    tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_content_title);


    // Add FragmentMain as the initial fragment       
    FragmentManager fm = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    FragmentHome fragment = new FragmentHome();
    ft.add(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}

public void toggleMenu(View v){
    mainLayout.toggleMenu();
}

// Perform action when a menu item is clicked
private void onMenuItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String selectedItem = lvMenuItems[position];
    String currentItem = tvTitle.getText().toString();

    // Do nothing if selectedItem is currentItem
    if(selectedItem.compareTo(currentItem) == 0) {
        mainLayout.toggleMenu();
        return;
    }

    FragmentManager fm = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String[] menu = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);
    if(selectedItem.compareTo(menu[0]) == 0) {
        fragment = new FragmentHome();
    } else if(selectedItem.compareTo(menu[1]) == 0) {
        fragment = new FragmentSettings();
    }
    if(fragment != null) {
        // Replace current fragment by this new one
        ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, fragment);
        ft.commit();
        // Set title accordingly
        tvTitle.setText(selectedItem);
    }

    // Hide menu anyway
    mainLayout.toggleMenu();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mainLayout.isMenuShown()) {
        mainLayout.toggleMenu();
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

}

Comment: What's in your custom layout? `com.example.layout.MainLayout`

Comment: I've added the code, please check it

Comment: Why are you using `com.example.layout.MainLayout` (which btw is not your MainActivity class) and not something like `LinearLayout`?

Comment: its my MainActivity, I'm using a custom framelayout for the sliding menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it.
I had to add on my fragment

```
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(MYeditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solved it while putting the below code in the MainActivity OF Frame Layout

```
   <activity 
        android:name="com.shane.pir.carhire.MainActivity"            
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >

    </activity>
```